# Simulation of an op-amp divider in LTspice

Tags: operational-amplifier

I would like to build up an op-amp circuit which can simulate the divide operation.

My thought is to build a log Op, then a substract Op, and finally use an exponential Op.

I would like to ask if there is any easier way to build up this function.

Below schematic is my analog divider circuit.
I have a problem that after I get Log and substract, I could get the right value as I finish exponential.

[image]

Comment: You can also place an analog multiplier in an opamp feedback loop ... https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-079.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using log, diff and anti-log is the very basic method of taking analog division:

$$
e^{\log_ea-\log_eb}=e^{\log_e\frac{a}{b}}=\frac{a}{b}
$$

For log and anti-log operations diodes are used along with op amps. The accuracy depends on the diode (p-n junction) characteristics because of their "non-idealities", so if you build the circuit the results might get off by some amount in either direction therefore requires calibration.

Possible options:

- You can have a look at TI's op amp circuit collection (AN-31). There's a multiplier/divider — it's not what you are looking for but may give you an idea.
- Although can't be sim'd with LTspice, you can go for a digital solution such as an MCU with ADC and DAC, along with a PGA, preferably.
- Or you can go for a real-time ACU (analog computational unit). **AD538** is an old one I can remember. Not sure if can be found in LTspice lib, though.

Comment: It would not be hard to construct an AD538 model from the block diagram. Don't even need transistors (though using them also wouldn't be hard.) For example, `.subckt` ... `B1 out 0 v= v(1)*v(2)/v(3)` .... `.ends`, like that. Of course, that may defeat the purpose of the question, too. Your answer point remains. AN-31, for example.